# Python HTTPX post Request timeout

Tags: python-3.x, timeout, monitoring, httpx

We have a python 3.8 application that monitor others application and generate metrics for grafana
Configuration:
python 3.8,
httpx 0.24.1
httpcore 0.17.2
Sometimes a check on applications failed with a request timeout exception:

```
 with httpx.Client() as c:
                response = c.post(self.url, data=body, headers=SOAP_HEADER, timeout=60)
            return self.soap_response(response)
        except Exception as ex:
            logger.info('Error during retrieve search for car parks at %s : %s', self.url, ex)
            return self.soap_error(ex=ex, code=500)
```

```
2023-06-21T16:13:07.709677822+02:00 [2023-06-21 14:13][INFO   ][ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0][eileo.internal.utils] : Loading template 'cxf_xmlrpc_search_for_car_parks.xml' at location : /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/eileo/internal/templates/cxf_xmlrpc_search_for_car_parks.xml
2023-06-21T16:13:07.743971031+02:00 [2023-06-21 14:13][INFO   ][ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0][httpx] : HTTP Request: POST https://ws.eileo.org/api/xmlrpc "HTTP/1.0 408 Request Timeout"
```

Httpx is a test, we have the same problem with request, we try to use different header (connection close, user agent), but it seems to have no effect. We have different layer (Firewall, Ingress, traefik) but the firewall has not blocked any request, and others applications have nothing in their logs.

Application is also monitor by actuator and had no access problems at this time.

The problem is the monitored application seems to not have been requested.
Second point, the timeout was set to 60s, how can we have a request timeout after 30ms ?
Any ideas in what direction search ?